# Skype Web SDK Oauth2 authorization invalid resource

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, skype-for-business

I am trying to integrate Skype for Business with my app using Skype Web SDK, but I cannot even complete authorization. This is my code based on the code from this video: https://youtu.be/EyHL1HH9FzE?t=20m20s

```
public connect() {
    var client_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    if (!/^#access_token=/.test(location.hash)) {
        console.log("no token");

        location.assign(
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize"
            + "?response_type=token"
            + "&client_id=" + client_id
            + "&redirect_uri=" + location.href
            + "&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com"
        );
    } else {
        console.log("token present");
    }
}
```

I am being redirected to the microsoft page, where I can log in, however next I am being redirected back to my app with the following url: `http://myapp/ui/index.html#error=invalid_resource&error_description=AADSTS50001%3a+Resource+identifier+is+not+provided.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+0efb74b9-6063-4046-9710-836d43641d00%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+7fcbee4c-e543-4b00-a485-152779f346bb%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-06-13+13%3a52%3a30Z`

So it says the error is

> an invalid resource and that the resource identifier is not provided.

I have copied the resource part from the video and have seen it in multiple other tutorials

```
+ "&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com"
```

In azure I have set `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true` and delegated permissions for Skype for Business Online are also added to that app.

Comment: I had similar error with Graph (not sure if this is the case here but worth to try) - have you tried changing to `resource=https%3A%2F%2webdir.online.lync.com`?

Comment: thanks robdy, but it unfortunately didn't work. i get exactly the same messages back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> an invalid resource and that the resource identifier is not provided.

I also can reproduce the issue you mentioned if I use [location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). It seems that **CORS** prevent it. It is not related with `resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com`

> Note that security settings, like **CORS**, may prevent this to effectively happen

**Solution:**

```
window.location.href = href
```

Please have a try to use the following code, then it works correctly on my side. For more information, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/ptauthazuread).

```
 var client_id = "xxxx"
 window.sessionStorage.setItem('client_id', client_id);
 var href = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=';
 href += client_id + '&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com&redirect_uri=' + window.location.href;
 window.location.href = href;
```